# Convert Int value to hexadecimal in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to convert the int value into Hexadecimal in dart.

```
    void main() {
      final myInteger =62535;
      final hexString = myInteger.toRadixString(16);
      print(hexString);
    }
```

It shows f447. But I want 0Xf447.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the prefix yourself:

```
void main() {
  final myInteger = 62535;
  final hexString = myInteger.toRadixString(16);
  print('0X$hexString');
}
```

OR

```
void main() {
  final myInteger = 62535;
  final hexString = '0X${myInteger.toRadixString(16)}';
  print(hexString);
}
```